# how to install Padre in linux(CentOS)?

Tags: linux, centos, perl

How to install `Padre IDE`  tool in Linux(Centos) for Perl scripting language?

Comment: Have you given [these](http://mail.perlide.org/pipermail/padre-dev/2010-June/001863.html) directions a try?

Comment: Is there any other IDE tool?

Comment: I'm no perl jockey, but `vim` is the best editor I've used for pretty much anything.  I know others who swear by SlickEdit, but it's not free.

Comment: `vim` is editor or IDE tool?

Comment: You can either use an EPEL package or http://padre.perlide.org/trac/wiki/DownloadCPAN . I hate to point this out but the installation of Padre is quite well documented in the Padre website.

Comment: @ Sami Laine, there is ni documentation for Linux(Centos)

Answer (score 2):

First, install cpanm (http://cpanmin.us/)

Next, install some required RPM:

```
sudo yum install wxGTK-devel perl-ExtUtils-Embed perl-File-HomeDir perl-Term-ReadLine-Gnu
```

maybe

```
sudo yum install wxGTK3
```

Next, install some required CPAN modules:

```
sudo cpanm Fatal Module::Pluggable Alien::wxWidgets Debug::Client DBD::SQLite::db ORLite ORLite::Migrate
```

Last step:

```
sudo cpanm Padre Padre::Plugin::Git
```

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the instructions on the padre [wiki](http://padre.perlide.org/trac/wiki/Download), selecting the Fedora installation. Or follow the instructions for [installation from CPAN](http://padre.perlide.org/trac/wiki/DownloadCPAN):

```
cpan Padre
```

Comment: i tried cpan Padre but i'm getting some error

Comment: @user3021349 if you want us to help you, you are going to have to be a tad more specific than "I got _some_ error". What error?